# Changing the color of the datatable rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a data table with many rows and for the sake of convenience Ill just use only two columns.
Below are the two columns in the datatable.

```r
rawdata <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  time = c(45,92,30,100,79,199,248)
)
```

I want to color the entire row of the dt based on certain conditions.

1. If `id=1` , I should be able to apply
   `backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(30,50), c('#C6EFCE', '#FFEB9C','#FFC7CE'))`
2. If `id=2` , I should be able to apply
   `backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(45,90), c('#e60000, '#000000','#ffffff))`
3. If `id=3` , I should be able to apply
   `backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(x,y), c('a, 'b,'c))`

Please find my current code for the datatable

```r
library(DT)
datatable(
  rawdata,
  rownames = FALSE,
  options=list(
    pageLength = 20,
    scrollX = TRUE, 
    dom = 'prlti',
    initComplete =JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '20px','background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"),
    columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets ="_all")),autowidth=T)
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    colnames(rawdata)[1:NCOL(rawdata)],target = 'row',
    # color =styleInterval(c(30,35), c('black', 'black', 'black')),
    backgroundColor =styleInterval(c(48,120), c('#C6EFCE', '#FFEB9C','#FFC7CE'))

  ) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = c(1:NCOL(rawdata)),'font-size' = '25px',fontWeight = 'Bold')
```

Comment: I edited your code that `rawdata` is usable. Still I get `Error in name2int(name, names, rownames) `. You probably have a typo in the first `formatStyle()` - it does not make sense to start with 11 here

Comment: Well, that wasn't a typo.
Like I said, I am just giving you a set of columns from my original data table.
I just wanted to know the logic of how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, I would store the color you want in each row of the table itself, and then use `styleEqual` to set the color of each row.  (We'll also want to hide the column that contains the color.)

Add a column with the color you want to display for each row:

```
library(dplyr)
rawdata <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  time = c(45,92,30,100,79,199,248)
) %>%
  mutate(row.color = case_when(id == 1 & time <= 30 ~ "#C6EFCE",
                               id == 1 & time <= 50 ~ "#FFEB9C",
                               id == 1 ~ "#FFC7CE",
                               id == 2 & time <= 45 ~ "#E60000",
                               id == 2 & time <= 90 ~ "#000000",
                               id == 2 ~ "#FFFFFF",
                               T ~ "#888888"))
```

(I used gray for `id = 3` since the original post omits the actual colors for that condition.)

Use `styleEqual` to set cell colors in the `time` column and `columnDefs` to hide the column with color hex values:

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  rawdata,
  rownames = FALSE,
  options=list(
    pageLength = 20,
    scrollX = TRUE, 
    dom = 'prlti',
    initComplete =JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '20px', 'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"),
    columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"),
                      list(targets = 2, visible = F)),
    autowidth = T)
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    c("time"), "row.color",
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(sort(unique(rawdata$row.color)), sort(unique(rawdata$row.color)))

  ) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = c(1:NCOL(rawdata)),'font-size' = '25px',fontWeight = 'Bold')
```

We get the following result:

[image]

If you want to render white text in black rows, you can add yet another column with `text.color` and use `styleEqual` with the `color` option too.

Comment: When I remove the "target=row", so i can just get the color for specified columns, it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: why doesn't it give me the desired result?

Comment: To make sure I understand - you want just the `time` column (and maybe some other columns in your full dataset) to have the color specified by `row.color`?

Comment: Yes,Thats exactly what I am talking about

Comment: Edited the post so that only the `time` column gets colors; you can add more column names to `c("time")` to include/exclude exactly the right set of columns in the full dataset.